# Re: Extracting content from API, stops halfway

Tags: json, python-2.7, wikipedia-api

I have encountered a problem and this script which I wrote. A month ago it works perfectly fine. But last night I tried it, it stop after getting like 10-15 articles. I have no idea why.

My code is as follows:

```
def getContents(keyword):

    f1 = open('NoRepeatedWords.text', 'r')
    line1 = f1.read().splitlines()
    f3 = open(filename, 'w+')
    count = 0
    for line in line1:
            try:

                print('======'+line + '======')
                count = count + 1
                print( 'The count is: ' + str(count))
                #to get the contents from the URL

                url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles='+urllib2.quote(line)+'&explaintext=1&exsectionformat=wiki'

                # print the article title 
                f3.write('=='+ ' '+ line.strip()+ ' ' +'==' + "\n"+ "\n")

                #category itself  
                opener = urllib2.build_opener()
                opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]  
                json_obj = opener.open(url)
                data1 = json.load(json_obj)

                for i in data1['query']['pages']:



                    f3.write((data1['query']['pages'][i]['extract']).encode('utf8')+"\n"+"\n"+"\n")




            except Exception:

                pass

    f1.close()
    f3.close()
```

What this code does is just to extract the contents of the api based on the keywords in NoRepeatedWords.text. These keywords are actual article title from wikipedia.

Just an example put one of the keyword into the text "KEY WORD HERE", it will display information in JSON formatt:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=KEYWORD HERE &explaintext=1&exsectionformat=wiki

Is it possible that it is because of server time out or the connection is terminated suddenly?

My keywords are as follows:

```
Outline of political science
Politics
Body politic
Criminalization
Criticism of science
Crossing the floor
Death in office
Extrajudicial killing
Index of gun politics articles
Index of politics articles
Island Chain Strategy
Judaism and political radicalism
Legislation
Libertarian anarchism
Monarch
Political movement
New public management
North Atlantic or liberal model of media and politics
Outpost (civilian)
Pacification theory
Pandering (politics)
Parliamentary leader
Parliamentwatch
Participation inequality
Polarization (politics)
Political abuse
Political argument
Political climate
Political crisis
Political demography
Political faction
Political globalization
Politically exposed person
Politicized issue
Politics of outer space
Politics of the International Space Station
Postfeminism
Proto-fascism
Outline of public affairs
Public interest
Public opinion
Public speaking
Publics
Punk ideologies
Puppet ruler
Regional autonomy
Sexualization
Spin (propaganda)
Spin room
Technoculture
Term of office
Testing the waters
Transparency report
Tribal chief
Two-step flow of communication
Veto
World domination
Affair
Apoliticism
The arts and politics
Bisexual politics
Corporate welfare
Courtesy resolution
Political crime
Denialism
Haldane principle
Health policy
Modified Scheme of Elementary education 1953
Issue voting
National language
Policy
Policy studies
Politicization of science
Power vacuum
Redistribution of income and wealth
Science policy
Single-issue politics
Social issue
Politics and technology
Transparency (behavior)
Urban politics
Workplace politics
Nicholas Young (MTPD)
Political lists
Lists of active separatist movements
List of Chinese spy cases in the United States
List of countries without political parties
List of coups d'état and coup attempts
List of coups d'état and coup attempts by country
List of coups d'état and coup attempts since 2010
List of cults of personality
List of foreign ministry headquarters
List of genocides by death toll
List of political conspiracies
List of countries by consultation on rule-making
List of highest paid mayors
List of historical separatist movements
List of kingdoms and royal dynasties
List of micronations
List of overseas visits by Tenzin Gyatso the 14th Dalai Lama outside India
List of peasant revolts
List of political movements named after dates
Newspaper endorsements in the United States presidential election, 1900
Newspaper endorsements in the United States presidential election, 1904
Newspaper endorsements in the United States presidential election, 2012
Newspaper endorsements in the United States presidential election, 2016
List of Occupy movement protest locations
List of people declared persona non grata
List of political catchphrases
List of political dissidents
Political gaffe
Political ideas in science fiction
List of revolutions and rebellions
List of scandals with "-gate" suffix
List of political party symbols
Table of voting systems by country
Timeline of the South China Sea dispute
List of United States presidential electors, 1792
List of United States presidential electors, 1796
List of wars between democracies
List of wars by death toll
Activism
9/11 Truth movement
1984 Network Liberty Alliance
Ableism
An Act of Conscience
Acting Witan of Mercia
Activism at Ohio Wesleyan University
Activism industry
Activist ageing
Activist knowledge
AirportWatch
Anarcho-punk
Anatopia
Anti-Capitalist Convergence
Anti-schooling activism
Antimilitarism
Artivism
Artivist Film Festival & Awards
Asia Catalyst
Außerparlamentarische Opposition
Australian Young Greens
Autistic Self Advocacy Network
Avaaz
Babels
Back-story (production)
Blackout Day
Bolivarian Revolution
Brights movement
Buycott.com
Will Byrne
Cacerolazo
CAVE People
CEC European Managers
Center for Socialist Studies
Chengara struggle
Choice USA
The Cigarette Papers
Citizen's Charter and Grievance Redressal Bill 2011
Civil libertarianism
Civil society campaign
Clandestine Insurgent Rebel Clown Army
Cognitive activism
Community Front in Defense of Land
Community House (Salt River, Cape Town)
Consciousness raising
Constructive Program
Cordobazo
Corporate Watch
Counter-recruitment
Counterculture of the 1960s
CountyWatch
Craftivist Collective
```

The full list of keywords can be obtained here (there are 15,000 keywords) and these words are valid wikipedia article title: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1OJNca33pJXRGF5b1V1amcwMmM/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: There is no time out error or any message it is weird.

Comment: Please do not run queries against wikipedia.org like this (or any MediaWiki site really). You know all keywords beforehand so you can batch them into groups of 50 and supply each batch to the `titles` parameter, pipe-separated.

Comment: The fake "Mozilla/5.0" is not especially nice. How many requests per second are you making? You could try to add some sleep, even 0.1 second, just to make sure you don't make dozens.